# jquery form check, if value is empty, unbind submit click

Tags: jquery, forms, bind, unbind

I tried to write a jquery form check code, if value is empty / words lengh less than something, unbind submit click, show error hint in some div. then 5 seconds later, bind the submit click. [Code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwyun/1/), but the bind/unbind not work as my wish.

JS:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    if($('#title').val().length<10){
        $('#statue').append('You should type more than 10 words');
        $('#submit').unbind("click");
        setTimeout(function (){
            $("#statue").html("");
            $('#submit').bind("click");
        }, 5000);
    }
    if($('#content').val().length<20){
        $('#statue').append('You should type more than 20 words');
        $('#submit').unbind("click");
        setTimeout(function (){
            $("#statue").html("");
            $('#submit').bind("click");
        }, 5000);
    }
    if(!$('#type').val()){
        $('#statue').append('You should select one type.');
        $('#submit').unbind("click");
        setTimeout(function (){
            $("#statue").html("");
            $('#submit').bind("click");
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

​
HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="porcess.php">
    <input id="title" name="title" type="text" />
    <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea>
    <select name="type" id="type" size="5">
        <option value="a">Section A</option>
        <option value="b">Section B</option>
        <option value="c">Section C</option>
        <option value="d">Section D</option>
        <option value="e">Section E</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="statue"></div>​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code a bit.  I tend to cache my elements instead of instantiating them over and over.  I also created a separate function that will disable/enable the submit button instead of unbinding the click event, as I think this is more user-friendly than unbinding the click.  Lastly, I added a variable that will return true/false depending on the validation, that way you don't submit the form until everything is as you want it to be.

***[See working jsFiddle demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/QTVVe/)***

### Cache Elements

```
var $submit = $('#submit'),
    $statue = $('#statue'),
    $title = $('#title'),
    $content = $('#content'),
    $type = $('#type');
```

### Submit Click Handler

```
$submit.click(function() {

    var continueSubmit = true;

    if ($title.val().length < 10) {
        $statue.append('<br />Title needs more than 10 letters.');
        disableEnable(true);
        continueSubmit = false;    
    }

    if ($content.val().length < 20) {
        $statue.append('<br />Content needs more than 20 letters.');
        disableEnable(true);
        continueSubmit = false;
    }

    if (!$type.val()) {
        $statue.append('<br />You must select 1 type.');
        disableEnable(true);
        continueSubmit = false;
    }

    return continueSubmit;
});
```

### Function to Disable/Enable Submit Button

```
function disableEnable(isDisabled) {

    if (!isDisabled) { $statue.html(''); }
    $submit.prop('disabled', isDisabled);
    setTimeout(function() { disableEnable(false); }, 5000);

}
```

Comment: I don't like the ideea of disabling the button for 5 seconds. Maybe the validation stops at the last step (select an option) and the user selects it in one second and then wants to resubmit. He now has to wait 4 more seconds.

Comment: @gabitzish - That's what the OP wants. I'm not here to debate that. I do think however, that if you are going to require the user to wait 5 seconds, that they should know they are waiting. Disabling/Enabling the button at least shows them when they can click. The next step would obviously be to put an re-enable countdown next to the button to even further enlighten in the user.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks bad. You should reuse some of your blocks. 
I've update the jsFiddle, reused some code, and rearranged the functions : http://jsfiddle.net/kwyun/21/

Another thing i've modified is binding to another function instead of unbindig, because if the user clicks in that 5 seconds interval, the form will submit.

Later edit : You could abort the ideea of unbinding, instead you can return false if there is an invalid field and set the timer only for hiding the message. Here is updated jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kwyun/27/

Comment: in your code, if nothing fill in, it still would post. But I should make a judge if title and content words less than 10 and 20 or opinon is empty, unbind the click.

Comment: It doesn't post ... that is what "return false" is for. Are you sure  you checked the last jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kwyun/27/ ?

Comment: I think my solution is better than the one you've selected. I think it makes no logic to disable the sumbit button for 5 seconds, if the user can select an option in one second and resubmit.

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kwyun/17/

Either use `e.preventdefault` or change the submit `type = "button"`

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="porcess.php">
    <input id="title" name="title" type="text" />
    <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea>
    <select name="type" id="type" size="5">
        <option value="a">Section A</option>
        <option value="b">Section B</option>
        <option value="c">Section C</option>
        <option value="d">Section D</option>
        <option value="e">Section E</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="statue"></div>​
```

Hope this helps
cheers

Answer (score 0):

you should call `e.preventDeault()`

i update jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kwyun/9/

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to return `false` (or use `event.preventDefault`) when your validation fails, or the submit will continue normally. Second, you must do something to prevent the submit from happening during that 5 seconds wait that you want. Just unbinding the handler won't do, since it will default to the normal submit again, and I suppose you don't want that, right?

I'd suggest, instead of unbiding, bind it to another function, that exits silently while returning false. After those 5 seconds, bind it again to the original function.

*Edit:* Also note that [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) expects a second argument, the function to bind to the event. Just calling it with a single argument won't work. Check that second form, the one that accepts a boolen (preventBubble): that's probably what you need:

```
$('#submit').bind("click",false);
setTimeout(function (){
    $("#statue").html("");
    $('#submit').bind("click", yourFunction); // Remember to keep a reference to your function somewhere
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle as well.  Take a look.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/kwyun/29/)